How to Preserve Original Band Names When Exporting Images to GEE Assets?
In Google Earth Engine (GEE), when I import an image to gee asset from local, the band names appear as b* (e.g., b1, b2, etc.) instead of the original band names. Is there a way to ensure that the band names in the asset match the original image's band names?
When I open the local image in ArcGIS Pro, I find that the band names are not in the 'b*' format.
